# Get Minimum data id When using JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have Table Structure as below
[image]

And My Query is as below

```
SELECT *,MIN(node.rnode) AS minRnode 
FROM final_mlm AS node, 
final_mlm AS parent 
where node.lnode BETWEEN parent.lnode AND parent.rnode AND parent.id = 1 
AND node.placement='l'
```

This query is working quite fine but my requirement is I need an id which have `minRnode` As given in query in **output**..

What i have tried

```
SELECT *, MIN(node.rnode) as minn
FROM (
        SELECT * FROM final_mlm AS node,
        final_mlm AS parent 
        where node.lnode BETWEEN parent.lnode AND parent.rnode 
        AND parent.id = 4 
        AND node.placement='l' 
     ) as t on t.rnode=node.minn
```

But this returns an error maybe for duplicate of id.

This is my **[live code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29e8d8/2)** In Sql Fiddle.

My output for First Woking query is

```
id  sponserid   level   lnode   rnode   placement   id  sponserid   level   lnode   rnode   placement   minRnode
3   2           2       21      22      l           1   0           0       1       24                  6
```

So as per this output i need an id from table Which have minRnode(Monimum Rnode)  = 6

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I already explained still as per this scenario Output is `ID = 7`. it does not necessary to get all data. i need just an id

Comment: As to your own queries: 1) When selecting the same columns twice (i.e. `id` as `parent.id` and `node.id`) then don't `select *`, but select the columns explicitely and give them unique names (e.g. `select parent.id as parent_id, node.id as node_id`). 2) Dont `select *, min(something)`. `MIN` says you want to aggregate the rows, `*` says you don't. Read up on aggregation. Use sql mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY to help you for as long as you haven't mastered this topic. Your first query is invalid and its result is mostly arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks for this. but `select *` Is just for demo i am not using it in my programme.

Comment: Well, the duplicate ID error stems from this. And even if you replace `*` with column names in your queries, both remain invalid which ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY would demonstrate (by raising an error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution for your problem:

```
SELECT id 
FROM final_mlm
WHERE rnode IN (SELECT MIN(node.rnode)
                FROM final_mlm AS node 
                INNER JOIN final_mlm AS parent 
                ON node.lnode BETWEEN parent.lnode AND parent.rnode
                WHERE parent.id = 1 
                AND node.placement='l')
```

Link to the demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29e8d8/59

Comment: Maybe you want to add `AND placement = 'l'` to the main query. Depends on whether you require the ID's record to have this placement.

Comment: PLUS ONE (NICE USE OF IN).